# I can't seem to hide the navigation bar with my .net MAUI app

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I'm using .net MAUI to make an application. I'm working on a login page, which also acts as the root page of the navigation stack I'm using for navigation. Here's my page's XAML:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ProcedureScheduler.Pages.LoginPage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="1">
            <Entry x:Name="UsernameEntry"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Label Text="Username"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Entry x:Name="PasswordEntry"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                IsPassword="true"/>
            <Label Text="Password" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Button
                x:Name="LoginButton"
                Text="Login"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Clicked="LoginButtonClicked" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>`
```

And here's the AppShell xaml:

```
`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="ProcedureScheduler.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProcedureScheduler"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:ProcedureScheduler.Pages">
</Shell>
`
```

As you can see, I tried using the "Shell.NavBarIsVisible" property, but that didn't seem to do anything. I also tried using it on other pages of my application, and also had no results. Here's a picture of the login screen:

[A login screen with the navigation bar at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvWBJ.png)

Comment: How do you set the MainPage in App.xaml.cs? Are you using `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());` in App.xaml.cs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs [Disable the navigation bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/pages#disable-the-navigation-bar):

> While `Shell.NavBarIsVisible` can be set on a subclassed
> [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.shell)
> object, it's typically set on any pages that want to make the
> navigation bar invisible. For example, the following XAML shows
> disabling the navigation bar from a ContentPage.

So you need integrate the `LoginPage` into a Shell app, your **AppShell.xaml** should like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="ProcedureScheduler.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProcedureScheduler"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:ProcedureScheduler.Pages">


    <ShellContent Title="LoginPage"                           
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Pages:LoginPage}" 
                  Route="LoginPage"/>

</Shell>
```

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
      public App()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new AppShell();
           //MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
      }
}
```

Set the Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false" in **LoginPage.xaml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ProcedureScheduler.Pages.LoginPage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false">

 
</ContentPage>
```

**Output:**

[image]